# Issue with Knockout, Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am getting the following error on my web application using Knockout.js

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'
```

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        AjaxRequest();
    });

    function AjaxRequest() {
        $.post("../../Api/DisabilitiesHandler.ashx?method=get", function (data) {
            var viewModel = {
                disabilities: ko.observableArray(data)
            };

            ko.applyBindings( viewModel, document.body);
        });
    }

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'disabilitiesRowTemplate', foreach: disabilities }"></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="disabilitiesRowTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:
            <input data-bind="value: Name" /></td>
        <td>
           Active <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Active" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

And this is my model

```
public class Disabilities
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code of the web service

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/JSON";
DbsaDal.Entities.DBSAEntities db = new DbsaDal.Entities.DBSAEntities();
List<DbsaDal.Model.Disabilities> disabilities = DbsaDal.Entities.Disabilities.Get(db);
context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(disabilities));
```

Any suggestions on what to do? I have searched everywhere on the web and can't find anything useful

Update 1:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"Id":1,"Name":"Blind","Active":false},{"Id":2,"Name":"Mute","Active":true}] Knockout.js:92
```

Comment: Are you getting that error in javascript? If so, your browsers debugger would point out the line where the error is happening. Can you post the code where the error is happening?

Comment: Post the full error message, line number and file

Comment: I have updated my question. The error is happening in the Knockout.js file

Comment: Try just: ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem:

```
disabilities: ko.observableArray(data)
```

This piece of code should have been

```
disabilities: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(data))
```

Comment: You could also tell the $.post function that you're expecting a json response and jQuery will parse it into a JavaScript object automatically:

`$.post("url", function(data) { }, 'json');`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/